# Django Template Inheritance

Tags: django, django-templates

Okay, this one is completely blowing my mind.

I have a very simple _base.html, whose code reads as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
    {% load static %}

    <title>Welcome!</title>

    <!-- Includes jQuery UI -->
    <script type='application/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script type='application/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/cupertino/jquery-ui.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />

    <!-- Includes Columnal -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='{% get_static_prefix %}Columnal/columnal.css' type='text/css' media='screen' />

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='{% get_static_prefix %}Style.css' />

    {% block head %}
    {% endblock %}
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <table width='100%'>
            <tr>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <td>Welcome, {{user.username}}!</td>
                    <td align='right'><a href='logout/'>Logout</a></td>
                {% else %}
                    <td><a href='login/'>Login / Register</a></td>
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        </table>
    </header>

{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Of course, while intended to be extended by a child template, this page does make sense by itself, and indeed, when rendered, I see what I would expect and what I had intended.

However, when I tried to extend this file with a child template, I was getting some unexpected results, so I tried cutting it down to the absolute bare minimum, namely:

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}
```

Just a single line of code.  One would think that if I display this file, I get the exact same result that if I just displayed _base.html itself.  However, THAT IS NOT THE CASE.  For some reason, there is an extra white line of nothingness above the header when I use this trivial child template.  What's even weirder is that, if I select view source for both pages (i.e., the page I get directly from _base.html and the one I get from the child template) IT SAYS THAT THE SOURCE CODE IS EXACTLY THE SAME (I'm using Chrome).  How is it that two files, that should display the same page, give the same exact source code (according to the browser), but DISPLAY DIFFERENTLY.

This completely blows my mind and I have no idea what could be causing this.  The way I understand it, Django does it's thing behind the scenes and feeds the browser a raw HTML file, so that the browser shouldn't care how I generated the HTML, as long as it's the same.  How then could these two methods produce different results?  Any help at all would be much appreciated as I have been stuck on this for the past two days.

P.S.:  I am sorry that the code for _base.html is a bit long for a forum post.  I probably could have chopped off a bit, but as I have no idea what's going on here, I don't really have an idea of what matters and what doesn't, so I didn't want to take the risk.

EDIT:  As I mentioned before, (in Chrome) if I right-click and select 'View page source' for both pages, I get the exact same source code.  However, if instead I select 'Inspect element', the source code is not the same.  For some reason, when viewing the source code via 'Inspect element' using the child template version, I find all of the content in the `<head>` tag of _base.html located in the `<body>` tag of the source code I see.  Any idea why that would happen?

Comment: Sorry to say that I cannot reproduce this issue using the code you've provided; it seems that something else is afoot.

Comment: @Zach Snow:  By chance, what OS are you using?  I am on Windows . . .  could this possibly be making a difference?

Comment: Not sure if that would make a difference; I am on OS X myself.  Unfortunately there are a number of things that could be causing the difference (differing middleware, maybe even different template loaders, and so on).

Comment: I wound up fixing it.  I still don't know what was wrong, but I created a new project, and after placing the same code in that project, it worked.  I have no idea what it was, but the setup with my project must have been screwy before.

Answer (score 0):

Have you specified the correct path of the template directory in TEMPLATE_DIRS of settings.py. ?

Also have you tried to view the page clearing all the browsing data(cookies, cache, etc...) ?

May be the browser is caching data behind the scenes..

Comment: Yes, the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting was correct.  I never thought to clear the browser data, however, so I'll go and give that a try . . .